# How to get objects from different files into one file?

Tags: objects, import, linked-data

When I click open, I get to I wanted to open, but I lose everything else. How can I open two files into one?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are several ways to import other blender objects in to a blender file.

#### Copy paste

The simplest way is to have both blend files open, and simply copy the object from one file and paste it into the other.

Select the object in the 3D view, then with the mouse still in the 3D view press <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy. To paste the object in to the other file press<kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

#### Append

For the second method you only need the file that you want both objects inside to be open (prior to 2.8 you have to be in object mode), and then [Append](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries.html) the object you want.

1. File > Append (prior to 2.8 <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> opened the append window too)
2. Select the blend file that has the object you want
3. After opening the blend file go to the *Objects* and select the object you want by its name.
4. Click the *Link/Append from Library* button.

Comment: Apparently you have to be in object mode for this to work. Tried copying a model while in pose mode and it only copied the skeleton.

Comment: @Ajedi32 thanks for the reminder (edited the answer) Its simple things like this that us established users forget can trip up new users.

Comment: Opening both files and copy-paste... sounds nice / easy / perfect. But when I try to open second file, blender closes the first one. So how can you actually open more than one file at once?

Comment: Just open two instances of blender. Don't know what os you are on, but on windows it is as simple as opening blender again.

Comment: Should not need to have both files open at the same time. Copied obj. in file 1 should copy to your OS clipboard. Close file 1. Open file 2 and paste.  This worked in Blender 3.0 on Linux OS (XUbuntu 20.04.3).