# Is it possible to Link one or more layers from another .blend file?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

Is it possible to link all object on on layer, in another .blend file, into a scene?

I've read:

- [How can I reuse existing materials, objects, etc from an existing .blend?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend)
- [How to get objects from different files into one file? [duplicate]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21170/how-to-get-objects-from-different-files-into-one-file)
- [How to add an object from another scene? [duplicate]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-to-add-an-object-from-another-scene)

But those all give the solution for linking individual objects.

I would like to continue modelling an 'composite object' that is composed of many objects (some of which are parented to other objects), operators (including boolean) and materials, etc. organized across different layers, in a separate blender file, but be able to (sometimes) render this 'composite object' placed within a scene in another .blend file.

How can I link this 'composite object' in one .blend file for use in another .blend file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to do that the other way around - [link objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html#make-link) from the original scene into new one within one blend file.

[image: screenshot-of-menu-on-the-grey-background]

In that case you have the freedom to select objects as you wish, including [selecting objects by 3D layer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/selecting/tools.html#select-all-by-layer), selecting all the children of the parent or vice versa via [Select Grouped](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/selecting/tools.html#select-grouped) menu and so on.

Once objects are selected, in Object mode press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > *Objects To Scene* (additional scene should be already created). You can either render from that additional scene or link/append the scene into another blend via [Append or Link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html#append-and-link) and choosing *Scene*.

Comment: I must be a complete idiot, but... when I link the scene (newly created in the first .blend file) into the second .blend file, it shows up in the 'Outliner' but I can't render it together with the 'local scene' in the second .blend file?

Comment: Never mind, I apparently needed to 'Ctrl+L' the linked scene into the second .blend file to the existing scene in that file for it to work.

Comment: @Jacco Ctrl+L to link objects works only inside of one blend file. Generally this solution assumes linking objects to another scene of one file and only then importing that newly created scene. This is to have possibility to select by layer or by parent etc which won't be available when just linking into another file