# Blender link external scene in the existing scene

Tags: linked-data, scene, append

I have a wery complex scene with lots of objects, and I have to fragment my file in smaller parts to be able to work

I have basic file in whitch I shoud import the other files as objects, or as scenes.

If I import it as objects, and than if I make changes in the imported file, like adding more objects, than all the time I have to inport the newly created objects.

If I import as scene, there will be another scene created.

My question is if there is a way to import the file in a way, that if I add new objects, and I reload it, the newly created objects to appear in the same scene.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93705/is-it-possible-to-link-one-or-more-layers-from-another-blend-file

Answer (score 1):

We will use the [link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/linked_libraries.html) function (not the "append", which creates a full copy of your data and don't do any sync from the source file).

- From your "master file", separate your assets into groups ;
- Save each group alone in a separate "slave" file ;
- In your master file, delete everything, then use the menu File → Link and link every group you need from your slaves files.

That way, your master file contains only linked groups. And your other slaves .blend files each contain one group, which you can edit. The master file will receive the changes. If you ever create a new object in a slave file, don't forget to assign it to the group so he will be synced.