# How do you combine two different blender files?

Tags: blend-files

I have one file with a scene containing animation in one file and in the other file I have an object with armature. Is there any way I can bring the object with the armature into the file with the animated scene?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21170/how-to-get-objects-from-different-files-into-one-file and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23153/what-is-the-differance-between-linking-and-appending-an-external-blend

Answer (score 0):

I most often use append to combine two separate blend files. (File > Append)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to get an object into another file. You just can copy the object in the one file. Blender will remember it and you can just paste it in the other file. You also can export the model under file -> export. After that you can import it into the other file. The first way is much easier an also goes much faster. Remember, that they have the same origenpoint, so they fit together perfectly!

Comment: Exporting should be used exclusively to port stuff to other applications/game engines, and copy pasting should be used carefully. The recommended way is to use either appending or linking

Comment: Why is copy and pasting not good ? I dont get that.

Comment: Copy pasting may not correctly preserve linked data from other files or scenes, making them all local. It also duplicates any existing materials, textures or instanced data every time you paste, quickly bloating the file and loosing any relationships.

Comment: When I use append, it separates my object into multiple files(mesh, material, motion, etc.) when I tell blender to import everything, the object does not look the same as it did when it was in my original file.